# Manifest merge failed : Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

my project and android studio worked fine last night.but when i open android studio today getting below error.i didn't change anything.how can i fix this?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
    is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
```

this is my build.gradle

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.android.my.app"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0' 
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
        compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
        compile 'com.gdacciaro:iosdialog:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this at the end of your app module build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because there is implicit dependency for support library in your dependencies block.

You can find that **iOSDialog** is using support library version **26.+** implicitly from its build.gradle. Please look at its [module build.gradle](https://github.com/MagicDog707/iOSDialog/blob/master/iosdialog/build.gradle)

So, you need to decide to exclude the support library from iOsDialog or updating your build.gradle to use `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `Support Library` to version 26.

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile('com.gdacciaro:iosdialog:1.0.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-v7'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
}
```

I'm strongly against using `configurations.all {}` block because you can't isolate the problem of a specific dependency.